# net-snmp installation and configuration in red hat linux

Tags: snmp, net

How to start and configure net snmp in red hat linux (it is installed properly). I am a beginner here. Any steps or useful links to do that?

thanks regards

kkoder

Answer (score 1):

To start it

```
service snmpd start
```

To ensure that it starts at boot

```
chkconfig snmpd on
```

Edit your /etc/snmpd/snmpd.conf file and make sure that your community strings are set to something non-default (i.e. not "public").

Other than that, what are you trying to achieve with SNMP?  Cacti integration (or some other monitoring system)?